# Apache does not show the browser

Tags: python, apache, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm running Selenium-Python tests on a website.

The goal:
Handling multiple users sending the requests to the server app, i.e. the users' requests would be all processed (none dropped); it is not critical to process them concurrently.
The 'simple server' can't do this.
Apache should (sure, it is overkill), but I cannot figure out how to set it up - the Chrome browser starts but it never comes up (neither does FireFox).

The basic test setup:

- Browser (client) sends ajax request to the test machine
- The test machine (must be) Windows (Win10 currently; will move to Winserver2008)
- The test machine runs the server app, Selenium (webdriver), and the browser (test)
- The server app receives the ajax call, and launches python app
- The python app launches webdriver
- webdriver starts and displays the browser (test)

This all works for a single user when I use a simple server app based on CGIHTTPRequestHandler.

If Apache is used:

1. Apache replies to the ajax request
2. Apache starts the python app
3. The python starts the webdriver - I get the PID, it is in the TaskManager, it takes up one core for minutes, before it exits
4. The browser (Chrome) starts - I see it in the TaskManager
5. but the browser does not come up

Environment:

- Win10 64-bit
- Python 3.5 (Anaconda)
- Selenium 3.4.3
- Chrome 59
- ChromeDriver 2.30
- Apache 2.4
- the url is the standard Apache page "http://localhost/index.html"

What I tried:

- Apache listens on its own port:

> Listen 127.0.0.1:1909

(the simple server listens on 1908)

- all Chrome instance were shut down before triggering the webdriver
- Chrome uses a separate test-profile; the python call is like this:

> driver = webdriver.Chrome(
>          executable_path="C:\WebDriver\chromedriver.exe",
>          service_args=[
>          "--user-data-dir=C:\Apache24\Google\Chrome\AutomationProfile",
>          "--verbose",
>          "--log-path=C:\WebDriver\logs\qc.log"])

but a directory, like "scoped_dir13752_2712", is always created in \Windows - is that an issue?

- comparing the webDriver logs (each ~1K lines) from 'simple server' (Chrome opens) and Apache (Chrome does not come up), nothing jumps out
  -

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the old reply, was researching a related issue.

for the webbrowser to be visible, httpd.exe needs to be running as the same windows user who is running the current desktop session. (don't install apache as a service)

I had a similar setup to you, but once upgrading to apache/2.4.33 I can no longer get chromedriver.exe nor geckodriver.exe to stay running, only phantomjs.exe which is lacking these days.